# Boot2Docker on Mac - Accessing Local Files

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

I've just set up boot2docker on my Mac. How do I go about mounting a local directory on my Mac so that it's accessible all the way through to a running Docker container? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Checkout the boot2docker docs, it has some stuff about just this.

Answer (score 11):

As of October 16, 2014, Docker supports mounting directories in the /Users path seamlessly.

From the [Docker blog](https://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/):

> With this release we are addressing the most common issue: sharing directories between your Mac and your containers. Using Docker 1.3 with the corresponding version of boot2docker, host-mounted volumes now work the way you expect them to.
>
> ...Note that there are still some limitations: for example this feature is limited to boot2docker’s virtualbox configuration, cannot be managed dynamically, and only works for directories in /Users . But we are receiving exciting contributions to improve volume management, so expect this area to improve drastically in the next few releases.

Example usage:
`$ docker run -v /Users/bob/myapp/src:/src [...]`

Comment: Is this supported on Linux too? Googles `gcloud` tools requires boot2docker and doesn't even provide a way to pass command line arguments to Docker.

Comment: I've only used Docker natively on Linux, so I'm not sure. Might be worth opening a separate question for.

Comment: This only works if the directory is inside your User folder. If it isn't (e.g. if it's on another hard drive), this won't work.

Comment: It works, but you have to know that virtualbox shared folder are very slow. it's better to configure a standard network shared folder.

Comment: To get this working on Docker 1.8 with Docker-toolbox, I had to use the full path. docker run -v ./dir:/dir [..] did not work. Yet docker run -v /Users/bob/dir:/dir [..] did.

Answer (score 7):

### boot2docker with share other than /Users

see https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/678.

Share your folder with the VM:

`VBoxManage sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm --name /tmp/Work --hostpath /CODE --automount`

Based on info found un [`bootscript.sh`](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/cd64edaca9241394d9223b32a2c705c42f02a40d/rootfs/rootfs/bootscript.sh), you know that the VM will run a `bootlocal.sh` script that is in the [`/var/lib/boot2docker`](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#persist-data) folder, where data persists.

Add a file `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# bash is not available!
mkdir -p /CODE
mount -t vboxsf /tmp/Work /CODE
```

Then `chmod +x /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh` and reboot your `boot2docker-vm` vm.

Answer (score 3):

**boot2docker together with VirtualBox Guest Additions**
How to mount /Users into boot2docker

https://medium.com/boot2docker-lightweight-linux-for-docker/boot2docker-together-with-virtualbox-guest-additions-da1e3ab2465c

> tl;dr Build your own custom boot2docker.iso with VirtualBox Guest
>   Additions (see [link](https://gist.github.com/mattes/2d0ffd027cb16571895c#file-readme-md)) or download
>   http://static.dockerfiles.io/boot2docker-v1.0.1-virtualbox-guest-additions-v4.3.12.iso
>   and save it to ~/.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso.

Answer (score 0):

As Levi mentioned, the /Users directory is auto-mounted. This is true in both boot2docker and docker-machine. That said, if you want to mount anything outside of /Users, all the current answers talk about Boot2docker. Since that's now deprecated in favor of docker-machine, this works for docker-machine:

First, ssh into the docker-machine vm and create the folder we'll be mapping to:

```
docker-machine ssh $MACHINE_NAME "sudo mkdir -p \"$VOL_DIR\""
```

Now share the folder to VirtualBox:

```
WORKDIR=$(basename "$VOL_DIR")
vboxmanage sharedfolder add "$MACHINE_NAME" --name "$WORKDIR" --hostpath "$VOL_DIR" --transient
```

Finally, ssh into the docker-machine again and mount the folder we just shared:

```
docker-machine ssh $MACHINE_NAME "sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=\"$U\",gid=\"$G\" \"$WORKDIR\" \"$VOL_DIR\""
```

Note: for UID and GID you can basically use whatever integers as long as they're not already taken.

This is tested as of docker-machine 0.4.1 and docker 1.8.3 on OS X El Capitan.