# Mounting nginx conf as a docker volume causes system error boot2docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm trying to run nginx within a docker container whilst mounting the configuration and static html files for it to serve up. Very simple stuff as far as I'm aware, but I keep getting an error about the directory not being a directory?

I'm running this example on my Mac using the latest version of Boot2Docker.

I have the following folder structure:

```
% tree                 ~/Projects/Docker/nginx-example
.
├── html
│   └── test.html
└── nginx.conf

1 directory, 2 files
```

The contents of the `nginx.conf` is as follows:

```
http {
  server {
    listen *:80; # Listen for incoming connections from any interface on port 80
    server_name ""; # Don't worry if "Host" HTTP Header is empty or not set
    root /usr/share/nginx/html; # serve static files from here
  }
}
```

I try to run the container (from within the `~/Projects/Docker/nginx-example` directory) like so:

```
docker run --name nginx-container \
  -v /Users/M/Projects/Docker/nginx-example/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
  -v /Users/M/Projects/Docker/nginx-example/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx:ro \
  -P -d nginx
```

> Originally I had tried something like `-v $(pwd)/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro` to keep the command shorter, but when it didn't work I thought I'd be explicit just in case there was some funky sub shell issue I wasn't aware of

And I get the following output

```
fc41205914098d236893a3b4e20fa89703567c666ec1ff29f123215dfbef7163
Error response from daemon: 
Cannot start container fc41205914098d236893a3b4e20fa89703567c666ec1ff29f123215dfbef7163: 
[8] System error: not a directory
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I'm missing?

### Mac Boot2Docker Volume issue?

I'm aware there is an issue with mounting volumes into containers when using Boot2Docker (although I'm led to believe this has long been resolved)

i.e. [Mount volume to Docker image on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348353/mount-volume-to-docker-image-on-osx/27540955#27540955)

But I followed the instructions there regardless, and it still didn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-v /Users/M/Projects/Docker/nginx-example/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx:ro`

you are attempting to mount a file to a directory - change that to:

`-v /Users/M/Projects/Docker/nginx-example/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro` and you should be fine. Take a look at the examples in the [Docker Volumes Docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

As well, `pwd` should work in the path. The shell expands this before the docker command is run, just like math and inner parenthesis, inner sub-commands are run first.

Comment: Doh! Of course :-( OK I'll check this when I'm back on my laptop. Thanks!