# How to have default file in image that I can override during container run?

Tags: nginx, docker

How to have default config file (that I copy to image during build) that I can override with -v option (or else), during container run?

**The details:**

*Imagine* I have following directives in Dockerfile:

```
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

I want that nginx used copied nginx.conf if no (single file) volume specified - like a default config, that always in the image.
And if I specify volume - container will use provided config file instead of copied to image.

So main idea is to have default config that I can override.

Of course following solution is not working, and gives an error. But may be you know how to achieve similar behavior?

Comment: your `VOLUME` directive will erase what you just copied using `COPY` it seems to me...

Comment: Nope, docker will raise an error during image build:
    
`Step 20/25 : VOLUME /etc/nginx/nginx.conf cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists`

Comment: You can put another layer on it and again do the COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf with your desired configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mounting nginx conf as a docker volume causes system error boot2docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763172/mounting-nginx-conf-as-a-docker-volume-causes-system-error-boot2docker)

Comment: Please see the linked question for an example of how to mount the config file into the container. I suggest you remove the `VOLUME` line from your Dockerfile and try it without that. You should still be able to mount a local file into the container when running it.

Comment: @nwinkler Seem to be it is working, thank you. If you will provide detailed answer I will accept it. or i can answer this question by myself. What do you prefer?

Comment: Posted as an answer, please see below. Glad to hear that it's working!

Comment: @nwinkler Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you remove the `VOLUME` part from your `Dockerfile`. You can then overwrite the default configuration file when you run the container.

So in your `Dockerfile`, just put this:

```
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Then when you run the container, map in a local file with your configuration changes:

```
docker run -v ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro ...
```

This will allow you to provide a default configuration, but will also let you override it if required.