# boot2docker startup script to mount local shared folder with host

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

I'm running boot2docker 1.3 on Win7.

I want to connect a shared folder.

In the VirtualBox Manager under the image properties->shared folders I've added the folder I've want and named it "c/shared".  The "auto-mount" and "make permanent" boxes are checked.

When boot2docker boots, it isn't mounted though.  I have to do an additional:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf c/shared /c/shared
```

for it to show up.
Since I need that for every time I'll ever use docker, I'd like that to just run on boot, or just already be there.  So I thought if there were some startup script I could add, but I can't seem to find where that would be.

Thanks

EDIT: It's yelling at me about this being a duplicate of [Boot2Docker on Mac - Accessing Local Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212228/boot2docker-on-mac-accessing-local-files) which is a different question.  I wanted to mount a folder that wasn't one of the defaults such as /User on OSX or /c/Users on windows.  And I'm specifically asking for startup scripts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boot2Docker on Mac - Accessing Local Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212228/boot2docker-on-mac-accessing-local-files)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh` fits your need probably, it will be run by initial script `/opt/bootscripts.sh`

And `bootscripts.sh` will also put the output into the `/var/log/bootlocal.log`, see segment below (boot2docker 1.3.1 version)

```
# Allow local HD customisation
if [ -e /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh ]; then
   /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh > /var/log/bootlocal.log 2>&1 &
fi
```

One use case for me is

I usually put `shared` directory as `/c/Users/larry/shared`, then I add script

```
#/bin/bash
ln -s  /c/Users/larry/shared /home/docker/shared
```

So each time, I can access `~/shared` in boot2docker as the same as in host

see [FAQ.md](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/17.03.x/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition)  (provided by @KCD)

Comment: using docker version 1.6.2, everytime I edit /opt/bootlocal.sh to add start up command it vanishes when restarted.

Comment: it shall be /var/lib/boot2docker/boot2docker.sh, I don't know why @user3699741 edited my answer to wrong indication.

Comment: Nailed it!!!  One QQ:  where does the symlink /var/lib/boot2docker get mapped to on my host machine?

Comment: @EricManley , not sure which host machine do you mean ? if windows, no, it exist in docker host machines only.

Comment: Documented here: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/17.03.x/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition

Answer (score 7):

If using boot2docker (Windows) you should do following:

First create shared folder for boot2docker VM:

```
"C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage" sharedfolder add default -name some_shared_folder -hostpath /c/some/path/on/your/windows/box

#Then make this folder automount 
docker-machine ssh
vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
```

Add following at the end of profile file:

```
sudo mkdir /windows_share
sudo mount -t vboxsf some_shared_folder /windows_share
```

Restart docker-machine

```
docker-machine restart
```

Verify that folder content is visible in boot2docker:

```
docker-machine ssh
ls -al /windows_share
```

Now you can mount the folder either using docker run or docker-compose.
Eg:

```
docker run it --rm --volume /windows_share:/windows_share ubuntu /bin/bash
ls -al /windows_share
```

**If changes in the profile file are lost after VM or Windows restart please do following:**

1) Edit file C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh and comment out following line:

```
#line number 44 (or somewhere around that)
yes | "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" regenerate-certs "${VM}"

#change the line above to:
#  yes | "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" regenerate-certs "${VM}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help with this. An additional few flags I needed to add, in order for the new mount to be accessible by the boot2docker "docker" user:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o umask=0022,gid=50,uid=1000 Ext-HD /Volumes/Ext-HD
```

Answer (score 1):

With docker 1.3 you do not need to manually mount anymore. Volumes should work properly as long as the source on the host vm is in your user directory.

https://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/

Comment: Yes, the user directory is auto mounted at /c/Users.  I wanted an additional directory at /c/shared.  And I can get it, but I always have to mount it even though it's added in the shared folders in the vm, right next to the Users one.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make it work following Larry Cai's instruction. I figured I could make changes to "c:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows\start.sh", add below

`eval "$(./boot2docker.exe shellinit 2>/dev/null | sed  's,\\,\\\\,g')"`

your mount command

`eval "$(./boot2docker ssh 'sudo mount -t vboxsf c/shared /c/shared')"`

I also add the command to start my container here.

`eval "$(docker start KDP)"`