# Persist Changes for boot2docker guest additions

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have seen that the latest version of boot2docker has provided guest addition by default. It allows you to mount your home directory under /Users which is nice. However, I would like to mount more than 1 directory for my purpose. Assuming the path i want to add are /location/folder1 and /location/folder2, I have followed these steps:

1. I have created the Virtual Machine mount points like this:

   ```
   VBoxManage sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm -name name1 -hostpath /location/folder1
   VBoxManage sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm -name name2 -hostpath /location/folder2
   ```
2. Then i ran boot2docker ssh and edited /etc/rc.d/automount-shares to add

   ```
   try_mount_share /location/folder1 'name1'
   try_mount_share /location/folder2 'name2'
   ```
3. I ran the following:

   ```
   sudo /etc/rc.d/automount-shares
   ```

I happily mounts the folder which I want.

Then, I do `exit and boot2docker save`  to save the state of my changes. This works very well until I restart my machine. But the moment, I restart the host, everything is lost.

Is there a way I can persist the mountings ?

P.S. - I have added the guest addition and stored this folder for boot2docker 1.2 where you work around Dockerfile and [create your custom iso](https://medium.com/boot2docker-lightweight-linux-for-docker/boot2docker-together-with-virtualbox-guest-additions-da1e3ab2465c) but I am looking for a cleaner approach here since guest edition feature is available already.

Any help is really appreciable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [boot2docker startup script to mount local shared folder with host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639968/boot2docker-startup-script-to-mount-local-shared-folder-with-host)