# How to run or deploy an app with a git dependency to a private repo

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, dart-pub

My application has a Git dependency to a private BitBucket repository.

```
  my_package:
    git:
      url: git@bitbucket.org:myuser/mypackage.git
```

When I run

```
gcloud --verbosity debug preview app run app.yaml
```

I get

```
Resolving dependencies...
Git error. Command: git clone --mirror git@bitbucket.org:myuser/my_package.git /root/.pub-cache/git/cache/my_package-6fe77906161a7a9252973e29e39a4149b75f9a7e
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

I guess adding an `ADD` instruction to the `Dockerfile` would be a viable workaround.
The repo needs to be checked out to a local directory to make this work of course.

I tried:

```
FROM google/dart-runtime
ADD ../my_package ../my_package
```

https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add says

```
The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD 
../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to
send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.
```

It seems I have to move the `..my_package` directory into the `my_app` directory. This isn't beautiful :-(

When I add a bogus line to the `Dockerfile` `run` fails but if I add an `ADD ...` instruction it seems to be ignored entirely.

Comment: error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory

Looks like there is just some problem with ssh?

Comment: Is this a problem with private repos only or any repo that uses SSH?

Comment: I think it is only with private repos. Currently I try to create a Docker image from scratch with installed ssh-client and a SSH deployment key, but I'm not there yet. It seems pretty difficult to get files into a Docker image which are not in the directory containing the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Can you not use a different URL, that uses the http protocol?  Otherwise I think you'll have to instruct Docker to install ssh and maybe provide a ssh key like you're trying to do.

Comment: I think I got it working. I'll verify it tomorrow and add an answer.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer Can you please confirm if there is a different solution for this problem now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update 2

My previous solution is still very inconvenient because I have to check in every time before I re-launch the app.

With great support I found a much more convenient solution.
Instead of an symlink I mount the directory. See https://superuser.com/questions/842642 for more details.
I don't know if and how this can work on other oSes (Win, OX X, ...)

I mount `../my_package` to `docker/my_package` (instead of a symlink) and use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM google/dart

WORKDIR /app
ENV DART_SDK /usr/lib/dart

ADD dart_run.sh /dart_runtime/

RUN chmod 755 /dart_runtime/dart_run.sh && \
 chown root:root /dart_runtime/dart_run.sh

ADD pubspec.yaml /app/
ADD pubspec.lock /app/
ADD docker/my_package /my_package
RUN pub get
ADD . /app/
RUN pub get --offline

## Expose ports for debugger (5858), application traffic (8080)
## and the observatory (8181)
EXPOSE 8080 8181 5858

CMD []
ENTRYPOINT ["/dart_runtime/dart_run.sh"]
```

#### Update 1

It turns out just serving the `.git` directory of the checked out package though `git-daemon` is a much more convenient solution.
All I had to do was setting all up according to the docs at https://www.dartlang.org/cloud/ and use a git dependency in `pubspec.yaml` to this repo served by git-daemon.

```yaml
  my_package:
    git:
      url: git://192.168.2.96/my_package
      ref: test
```

This url works when working locally and also within the Docker container.

#### Original

I can run my app with this Dockerfile

```dockerfile
FROM google/dart

WORKDIR /app

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y openssh-client

ADD tool/bitbucket_deployment_key /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN \
  mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
  echo "Host bitbucket.org" >> /root/.ssh/config && \
  echo "    StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /root/.ssh/config && \
#  ssh-keyscan -t rsa -H bitbucket.org,131.103.20.167 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts && \
  chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
  eval $(ssh-agent) && \
  ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN \
  git clone git@bitbucket.org:myuser/my_package.git /my_package --branch test && \
  rm /root/.ssh/id_rsa

#ENV DART_SDK /usr/lib/dart

ADD dart_run.sh /dart_runtime/

RUN chmod 755 /dart_runtime/dart_run.sh && \
  chown root:root /dart_runtime/dart_run.sh

ADD pubspec.yaml /app/
ADD pubspec.lock /app/
RUN pub get
ADD . /app/
RUN pub get --offline

# Expose ports for debugger (5858), application traffic (8080)
# and the observatory (8181)
EXPOSE 8080 8181 5858

CMD []
ENTRYPOINT ["/dart_runtime/dart_run.sh"]
```

I created `id_rsa` with ssh-keygen without a passphrase. This is the reason I delete the file from the image after the `git clone` command. It isn't used afterwards anyway.

In my BitBucket repo I added `id_rsa.pub` as a deployment key.

Comment: clever idea. Did you try simply making `my_package` a git dependency? Since you installed the ssh key the pub get should resolve it then right?
Unless of course, your git repo contains more than one dart package (as mine does)

Comment: As far as I know a git dependency with a repo containing more than one package is generally not supported by `pub`. I got it working with a git dependency to the bitbucket repo. The problem was the authentication but I got it working (see my answer). But I figured that it is more convenient to make the container load the files from the checked out directory because I don't have to check in every change to make it take effect in the container.

Comment: Yes I've just cut over to using your git clone trick above and it is tedious having to check in all the time. Also it runs into docker image cloning so that breaks things if you push new changes to your repo. I'll need to look at restructuring my code so I can go back to working with local projects. I might try symlinks

Comment: Actually I have to check in locally to make it work, but I don't need to push. Basically any method copying over the network could be used instead.

Comment: I'm going back to just normal paths but with the docker file up a couple of directories. Much easier to work that way but not too pretty

Comment: This way you need to change the `run.sh` file used to invoke `server.dart`, don't you?

Comment: Here is a similar question (not Dart related) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639968

Comment: Yes and app.yaml etc so not pretty. I'm considering automating those changes with grinder at some point so as it copies those files up to the parent directory it modifies the paths appropriately

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you please confirm if there a better solution for this now ?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for adding this as an answer but am unable to comment without more reputation:

Please vote on google-cloud-sdk issue 93 if you would like this to be fixed:
https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=93