# Docker mounting volume for editing source code

Tags: docker

I have docker setup on my Windows system. The source code of the application is available at `C:\Application\source` location.
I want this information to be available within the docker container so that it is easy to make code changes during development without rebuilding the image.

This is what I tried

```
docker run -d -P -i -t -p 8083:8080 --name html-app -v /c/Application/source:/usr/src html-app-img:vnode
```

The image `html-app` is based on Node JS

Now when I do a `docker exec -it html-app /bin/bash` , it doesn't show the contents of `C:\Application\source` there.
I thought that should be available right?
In the Oracle Virtual box, I've shared the folder `C:\Application`

Is there anything else that I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Oracle Virtual box, I've shared the folder C:\Application

That is not enough. You need to modify your boot2docker image in order for the TinyCore Linux session to mount the shared path (only `C:\Users\<yourlogin>` is mounted by default as `/c/Users/<yourLogin>`)

See "[Docker Compose Mount Window Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498478/6309)"

> Edit/create (as `root`) `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh`, (sda1 may be different for you)
>
> Add:

```
mkdir -p <local_dir>
mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` <mount_name> <local_dir>
```

(the [mount might need `umask` option as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622676/6309))

Comment: Thanks Von. Let's say I have 'node_modules' folder inside /usr/src. So when I mount the source code (which doesn't have 'node_modules' folder) why doesn't both the layers show up? I see only the contents inside C:\Application\src now

Comment: If you see the content of Application/src, isn't it what you asked originally? And where is /usr/... ? Is it in your boot2docker session?

Comment: /usr/ is a work directory is created inside the container. Is there a way by which we can have contents from /usr and c:\Appllication\source?

Comment: Yes with -v, to mount the host folder to the container

Comment: I did that, but I see only the contents in C:/Application/src and not the one in /usr/src

Comment: @Apps when you say " I see only the contents in `C:/Application/src`", this is in the boot2docker Linux session, right? "and not the one in `/usr/src`": this time, it is in the container launched by `docker run`, correct?

Comment: @Apps Are you using a git bash or Cygwin on your Windows host? Or do you make your ssh session from a regular CMD shell? The former won't work well (https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/846#issuecomment-97526663)

Comment: I'm using the docker terminal that gets installed as part of docker-toolbox

Comment: @Apps try a simple CMD in which you type `docker-machine ssh <yourmachine>`

Comment: I'm able to ssh to docker-machine. But I still have the same issue