# docker : container exited when using -v option

Tags: docker

I'm actually trying to build a dev environment with Docker. So I'm trying to share a folder between my running container and my host system (windows 7).

To run my container I'm using this :

```
    docker run -d -P -v /c/project/webproject:/usr/src/app chris/node-web-app
```

This command "works well" and I got the container's ID, but I don't know why my container is stopped. I'm just able to see it by running :

```
    docker ps -a
```

I started Docker last weekend during a workshop for its third birthday, so any help will be very useful.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/c/project` won't be visible in your boot2docker VM.

Only paths started by /c/Users are automatically mounted by the VirtualBox VM.

See "[Boot2Docker VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions)" if you want to mount another folder.
See "[Docker mounting volume for editing source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608266/6309)" for a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer @VonC, but I'm using docker-machine and not Boot2Docker.
I found this issue https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1814

I add the shared folder with the VirtualBox GUI, but when I try to use :

```
    sudo mount -t vboxsf project /c/project
```

I got some errors : the option -t doesn't exist...

I also found this doc from docker : https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume

It still doesn't work for me...

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: You *are* using boot2docker: when you do a `docker-machine create -d virtualbox`, docker-machine will download `boot2docker.iso`, a VM image with docker pre-installed. The answer I gave will allow you to modify that image to add one more auto-mounted folder.