# mysql in docker container can't run through a mounted volume on os x

Tags: docker, boot2docker

On OS X.

I am trying to run mysql in a docker container through boot2docker, by mounting the volume `/var/lib/mysql` on the host, so that I can have persistant mysql data.
I plan to use a data only container in future, but right now I was trying to do this using this option.

I use the following command to run the container :

`docker run -v /Users/yash/summers/db:/var/lib/mysql -i -t 'image name'`

The `/Users/yash/summers/db` folder is already there.

I am facing persmission issues in this. Using commandline, I am able to access the directory, create/remove new files, but when I am running 
`service mysql start`, I get the following error:

```
150528 15:43:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150528 15:43:43 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150528 15:43:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 909 ... 
150528 15:43:43 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
150528 15:43:43 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.150528 15:43:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
150528 15:43:43 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
150528 15:43:43 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150528 15:43:43 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150528 15:43:43 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8 
150528 15:43:43 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150528 15:43:43 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150528 15:43:43 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150528 15:43:43  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
150528 15:43:44 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I have trying to solve this for the past 2 days, going through so many pages like [this](https://github.com/jjethwa/icinga2/issues/2), [this](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212228/boot2docker-on-mac-accessing-local-files).

I can't solve my problem. I think I am not able to perfectly do what the solutions are suggesting.

From my understanding, there are some workarounds listed on those pages which include changing the uids and guids, but I think they are not well explained.

Can anybody please explain to me a detailed workaround for this.

**Update 1 :** I tried the it with using a data only container also, and still facing the same issue.

I am able to run everything fine if I don't use any `-v` or `--volumes-from` option, so I think there is no prob in mysql server.

**Update 2 :**
Dockerfile used for creating the data-only container:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN mkdir /var/lib/mysql

VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: I tried with a data only container, and still facing the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. Looking for an answer as well

Comment: Can you use a entrypoint script where you change the owner of the mapped volume to be mysql user? I had a similar problem with postgresql in linux, I used a data container and changed the data folder to be owned by postgres user at container runtime, and it worked

Comment: @Yashasvi does my answer below help you? It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

There are two different solutions.

1. **Solution #1. With Dockerfile**

   (I don't like it because I prefer official image from Docker Hub without any changes)

   Add `RUN usermod -u 1000 mysql` to your Docker file to set ID 1000
   for user "mysql" ( the same ID like inside docker-machine).
2. **Solution #2. With my.cnf**.

   Still I am using my own config I prefer this solution. We alredy have root user with ID 1000, because of that we
   can run MySQL with this user:

   - **my.cnf**

     **Main row is `user     = root`** (you can use `sed` to change only this row in file. I prefer mount all file)

     ```
     [client]
     port        = 3306
     socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
     default-character-set = utf8

     [mysqld_safe]
     pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
     socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
     nice        = 0

     [mysqld]
     user        = root
     pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
     socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
     port        = 3306
     basedir     = /usr
     datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
     tmpdir      = /tmp
     lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
     explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
     init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
     init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
     character-set-server=utf8
     collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
     skip-character-set-client-handshake

     # Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
     # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
     #bind-address   = 127.0.0.1

     #log-error  = /var/log/mysql/error.log

     # Recommended in standard MySQL setup
     sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

     # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
     symbolic-links=0

     # * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
     #   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
     #
     !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
     ```
   - **Change default my.cnf with this file:**

     docker run -it -v ./mysql/var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -v ./my.cnf::/etc/mysql/my.cnf mariadb:10.0.22

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `docker run -v` option then docker don't manipulate with files ownership. So owner of the mounted folder inside container will have the same UID as in the host system (username can be different).
You can change ownership of the file or directory inside container by `chmod` command but it change ownership in host sytem too.
So you can prepare correct ownership on your host system before you run docker container.
This example demonstrates how it works (try it on your system):

I have ~/foo directory which is owned by me - my UID is 1000

```
~ $ ls -lnd foo
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1000 4096 Nov 24 22:47 foo
```

Run docker container, mount ~/foo directory to them and display ownership inside container

```
~ $ docker run -it --rm -v ~/foo:/tmp/foo busybox ls -ln /tmp
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     1000          4096 Nov 24 21:47 foo
```

Owner UID inside container is the same.
Now I change directory ownership on my computer.

```
~ $ sudo chown 1001 foo
```

Start container again, mount the foo directory and display ownership

```
~ $ docker run -it --rm -v ~/foo:/tmp/foo busybox ls -ln /tmp
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1000          4096 Nov 24 21:47 foo
```

Owner UID was changed as well

But there is one exception. If you try to mount volume to nonexistent directory then docker will create this missing directory automatically (but this is deprecated feature, so don't do this) and this directory will by created with UID 0.
Try it:

```
~ $ docker run -it --rm -v ~/foo:/tmp/bar/foo busybox ls -ln /tmp
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    3 0        0             4096 Nov 24 22:10 bar
```

Answer (score -1):

I similarly ran into this issue; I solved it by chmod/chown'ing inside my data container, e.g.:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Create data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data /var/lib/mysql
RUN chmod -R 777 /data /var/lib/mysql
RUN chown -R root:root /data /var/lib/mysql

# Create /data volume
VOLUME /data
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
```

I believe this works because UFS now properly records permissions rather than relying on a direct from host mount to do so, which as you've discovered, does not work on OS X

Comment: this answer isn't working for me in 1.8.1. Has anyone found a good solution?

Comment: @DanielPayne to be clear, are you using 2 containers, one for the DB the other as a pure "data only" container?

Comment: No would that solve the permissions problem? If so do u have an example data container for this?

Comment: yes: you need a "data only" container, separate from your DB container, and using the code provided above it will work. See here: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: is the code above for the data-container Dockerfile or the MySQL one?

Comment: @DanielPayne the data-only container