# Docker mounted volume not tracking nginx log files

Tags: linux, nginx, permissions, docker

So I actually "solved" this issue right before posting this question, but I'll ask it anyway because I'd like to know **why** what I did works,

I have nginx installed via brew and the docker nginx base image in my local machine.

I have the directory **/container/logs/nginx** and I'm mounting it to **/var/log/nginx** that's inside of a docker container using

```
docker run -d -P -v /container/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx nginx
```

I was expecting to see the access and error .log files in the mounted directory. However, nothing was there.

I thought maybe, even though there were no error messages, that there might be a permissions issue with mapping from a directory that resides in my root directory, so I instead mapped it to **/Users/jimmygong/containers/logs/nginx**, using

```
docker run -d -P -v /Users/jimmygong/container/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx nginx
```

This does work. Could someone walk me through exactly what's occurring here? Do I not have write permissions outside of my home directory (e.g. /Users/jimmygong)? I'm running Mac OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boot2Docker on Mac - Accessing Local Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212228/boot2docker-on-mac-accessing-local-files)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the `automount` script of `boot2docker` - I am assuming you are using `boot2docker` since you are using `brew` and your user dir starts with `/Users`. That and the fact you also need to tell virtualbox to expose your shared directory.

Imagine how your volume is shared:

```
your mac <--X--> boot2docker VM <----> nginx container
            \_ /Users is mounted properly, but not other dir.
```

see:

- [Boot2Docker on Mac - Accessing Local Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212228/boot2docker-on-mac-accessing-local-files)
- https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/rootfs/rootfs/etc/rc.d/automount-shares
- https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/678
- [Mount volume to Docker image on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348353/mount-volume-to-docker-image-on-osx/27540955#27540955)